# How to test logout while using tymon/jwt-auth in Laravel?

Tags: laravel, unit-testing, jwt

I'm trying to make a logout test for my api with `tymon/jwt-auth` package. Here I have defined the api routes, controller, and a unit test.

In `api.php`:

```php
Route::group(['middleware' => 'api', 'prefix' => 'auth'], function ($router) {
    Route::post('login', 'AuthController@login');
    Route::post('logout', 'AuthController@logout');
    Route::post('refresh', 'AuthController@refresh');
    Route::post('me', 'AuthController@me');

    Route::post('me/profile', 'AuthController@profile');
});
```

In `AuthController.php`:

```php
/**
 * Log the user out (Invalidate the token).
 *
 * @return \Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse
 */
public function logout()
{
    auth()->logout();

    return response()->json(['message' => 'Successfully logged out']);
}
```

In `tests/Unit/AuthenticationTest.php`:

```php
/**
 * Test if user can login trough internal api.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function testLogin()
{
    $response = $this->post('api/auth/login', [
        'email' => 'admin@xscriptconnect.com',
        'password' => 'password'
    ]);

    $response->assertStatus(200)
        ->assertJsonStructure(['access_token', 'token_type', 'expires_in']);

    $this->assertAuthenticated('api');
}

/**
 * Test if user can logout trough internal api.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function testLogout()
{
    $user = User::first();
    $user = $this->actingAs($user, 'api');

    $user->post('api/auth/logout')
        ->assertStatus(200)
        ->assertJsonStructure(['message']);

    $this->assertUnauthenticatedAs($user, 'api');
}
```

The login test works fine but when it starts the logout test, the assertion fails. It shows me this error:

```
There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Unit\AuthenticationTest::testLogout
Expected status code 200 but received 500.
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

And when I tested it using this method:

```php
public function testLogout()
{
    $user = User::first();
    $this->actingAs($user, 'api');

    $response = auth()->logout();
    $response->assertStatus(200);
    $response->assertJsonStructure(['message']);
}
```

I got this error:

```
There was 1 error:

1) Tests\Unit\AuthenticationTest::testLogout
Tymon\JWTAuth\Exceptions\JWTException: Token could not be parsed from the request
```

What is the proper way to test a logout trough this package? Please help.

Comment: You need to log the user out through the frontend, just delete the token.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [this comment](https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/issues/1246#issuecomment-350710974) in it's github page, I have found the solution for this problem. I changed my script like this and it works.

```php
/**
 * Test if user can logout trough internal api.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function testLogout()
{
    $user = User::first();
    $token = \JWTAuth::fromUser($user);

    $this->post('api/auth/logout?token=' . $token)
        ->assertStatus(200)
        ->assertJsonStructure(['message']);

    $this->assertGuest('api');
}
```

Please feel free to post another answer regarding to this question if any. Thank you very much.

Comment: This api was built for my react native application, I think I need it to be tested because there will be a logout button inside the app and the TTL will be lifetime to keep the user logged in until the logout button pressed no matter what. Just to make sure.. How do you think? Does this test is really not necessary?

Comment: Works fine, but `\JWTAuth::fromUser($user);` must be replaced with `\Tymon\JWTAuth\Facades\JWTAuth::fromUser($user);`

Answer (score 0):

Override the method `be()` in your `TestCase` to set the authorization header when use `actingAs()` aka `be()` method

```
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as UserContract;

abstract class TestCase extends BaseTestCase
{
    public function be(UserContract $user, $driver = null)
    {
        $token = auth()->fromUser($user);

        return parent::be($user, $driver)->withHeader('Authorization', "Bearer {$token}");
    }
}
```